# Unix Date YYYYMM to YYYYMMDD

Tags: date, unix

I have date in a variable

```
fvd=202201
```

I want to convert this to

```
fvd_yyyymmdd=20220101
```

I tried

```
fvd_yyyymmdd=$(date -d"fvd" +%Y%m01)
date: invalid date '202201'
```

Comment: `fvd_yyyymmdd=$(date -d"${fvd}01" +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: `fvd_yyyymmdd="${fvd}01"`